# How to apply label to Gmail Inbox Item using IMAP and PHP

Tags: php, gmail, label, imap, data-access

I want to apply label to some emails in my inbox and I use this code:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}';

$inbox = $hostname.'INBOX';
$mbox = imap_open($inbox, $username, $password) 
    or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$label_mailbox = $hostname.'test_label';
$copy_success = imap_mail_copy($mbox, '1,2,3', $label_mailbox);

if ($create_success) {
    echo 'Label added.';
} else {
    die('Cannot create mailbox: '.imap_last_error());
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($mbox);
```

But the result is:

```
    Cannot copy to mailbox : [TRYCREATE] No folder {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}test_label (Failure)
```

Can someone tell me why it does not work? I know for sure that this label exists.

Comment: Solution: 'label_mailbox = "test_label"'

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use just the label name without the host name. For example not

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}test_label
```

but

```
test_label
```